# Accessing hyperledger composer rest server access token from frontend client

Tags: angularjs, oauth-2.0, hyperledger-composer, passport-github2

I have a hyperledger composer network and rest server set up with github authentication(using passportjs). From the rest server I can successfully authenticate with github and get an access token that is in the local storage and displayed at the top of the explore page. However I am having trouble with how to make this `access_token` known to my frontend client(angularjs) for use in subsequent API calls. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this.storage.get(key);` to access local storage of browser and give access_token in place of key.